# Using "please" and "never"

Tags: word-usage

Can we use please and never together in the same sentence like ...

**Please never do that while you're walking.**

*or something like*

**You may get it from whichever store you like but please never visit that grocery store.**

And what about this sentence:

**Please don't ever do that.**

*Thank you*

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to say 'please don't ever', i.e.:

*'**Please don't ever** do that while you're walking.'*

*'You may get it from whichever store you like but **please don't ever** visit that grocery store.'*

I'm a native English speaker and that sounds more natural to me.

Comment: I rather like *please never*.

Comment: @tchrist Is it just about popularity and are both the sentence structures grammatically correct?

Comment: @user8718165 The *never* version feels a bit stronger to me.

Comment: @tchrist thank you. I value your opinion.